# TinyMCE ContextMenu mceInsertContent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, editor, tinymce, wysiwyg

I'm trying to add an option to the TinyMCE ContextMenu plugin and I have somewhat succeded. What I'm trying to do is that once clicked I would like a predetermined text snippet to be added to the editor. This is what I have so far:

```
t._menu = m;
am = m.addMenu({title : 'Message Personalizer'});
am.add({title : 'First Name', cmd : '**cmd**'});
am.add({title : 'Last Name', cmd : '**cmd**'});
am.add({title : 'Email Address', cmd : '**cmd**'});
am.add({title : 'Cell Phone', cmd : '**cmd**'});
```

This shows the menu correctly but I haven't been able to find any documentation that will let me use the command `mceInsertContent` on it. I normally can call `mceInsertContent` using `tinymce().execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,**mycontent**);` and it works without an issue. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to register a command:

```
m.addCommand('insertFoo', function() {
    m.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false , "Foo");
});

am.add({title : 'First Name', cmd : 'insertFoo'});
```

Comment: Thanks I was just able to figure this out by looking at the other plugins.